# Prove that two Cauchy sequences are convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Prove that $$x_n+y_n$$ is Cauchy without using the theorem: A sequence is Cauchy iff it converges to some point.

My attempt:

Assume that $x_n$ and $y_n$ are convergent. That is by definition $$\vert x_n - a \vert \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ $$\vert y_n - a \vert \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

$$\vert x_n -a \vert + \vert y_n - a \vert \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$ By definition of convergence $$x_n + y_n$$ is Cauchy

Comment: Did you mean  to write $y_n-a$ in the third stage?

Comment: yes my mistake.

Comment: We don't need to assume equal limit for $x_n$ and $y_n$.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @K.Gibson Can you please clarify: are you proving that the sum of two Cauchy sequences is Cauchy, or that the sum of two convergent sequences is convergent? As you say you are not allowed to use the equivalence of those two conditions, for the purpose of the proof we must first know which of those two conditions is at play here.

Comment: the sum of two convergent sequences are cauchy

Comment: @K.Gibson Would you mind stating that precisely in the question? The title says one thing and the text says another, and neither says what we can assume for $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$.

Comment: Yes the title is the question. I got them mixed up.

Comment: The only assumption is that they are Cauchy

Comment: @K.Gibson I've posted an answer, but there are other answers below, and due to not having the precise question to answer to - all those answers are to different questions. Hope one of them is to *your* question.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

- $\vert x_n - L_1 \vert \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$
- $\vert y_n - L_2 \vert \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

then by triangle inequality

$$\vert x_n+y_n-(L_1+L_2)\vert\le \vert x_n -L_1 \vert + \vert y_n - L_2 \vert \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$

and $x_n+y_n$ converges.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are two Cauchy sequences. We will prove that $(x_n+y_n)$ is Cauchy.

Pick $\varepsilon>0$. For this $\varepsilon$, there is $n_1\in\mathbb N$ such that:

$$|x_m-x_n|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\text{ for }m,n\ge n_1$$

and also there is $n_2\in\mathbb N$ such that:

$$|y_m-y_n|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\text{ for }m,n\ge n_2$$

Now let $n_0$ be the maximum of $n_1, n_2$. Then, for $m,n\ge n_0$ we obviously have $m,n\ge n_1, n_2$, so the following is valid (using the triangle inequality):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}|(x_m+y_m)-(x_n+y_n)|&=&|(x_m-x_n)+(y_m-y_n)|\\&\le&|x_m-x_n|+|y_m-y_n|\\&\lt&\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\\&=&\varepsilon\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. There are $N_1,N_2\in\mathbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N_1\implies\lvert x_n-a\rvert<\frac\varepsilon4\text{ and }n\geqslant N_2\implies\lvert y_n-b\rvert<\frac\varepsilon4.$$Let $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$. Then, if $m,n\geqslant N$, you have\begin{align}\bigl\lvert(x_m+y_m)-(x_n+y_n)\bigr\rvert&=\lvert x_m-a+a-x_n+y_m-b+b-y_n\rvert\\&\leqslant\lvert x_m-a\rvert+\lvert x_n-a\rvert+\lvert y_m-b\rvert+\lvert y_n-b\rvert\\&<\frac\varepsilon4+\frac\varepsilon4+\frac\varepsilon4+\frac\varepsilon4\\&=\varepsilon.\end{align}